# MATLAB C Binary files

Tags: c, matlab, file, binary

Our company uses STMCUBE IDE to write C programs for STM chips, and the decision has been taken that moving forward, we will use MATLAB.

My question concerns the .bin file produced post build. The chip range we use has quite small internal memory (128kb) and I have noticed that some of the .bin files we have written in MATLAB seem quite large. Does MATLAB produce larger binary files than would be expected if the code were 'hand written', so to speak?

Comment: It is likely that the automatically generated code is not optimal in space nor time. I guess it depends on what functionality you use. The benefit of using MATLAB is that it saves time writing the code.